# Unable to load quote object

Tags: sales, quote, ee-1.12

Does the `sales/quote` object work differently than other objects when loading? See the following..

Works:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $quoteId)
    ->getFirstItem();
print_r($quote->getData()); // shows right data
```

Does not work:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
print_r($quote->getData()); // empty
```

Both `$quote` are of the correct of class, `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`.

Comment: with 5 upvotes i dont understand how this question is marked as off-topic and non-reproducible. this problem can be reproduced. Simply load a quote on frontend order view page and on admin order view page, it will work differently.webbiedave's answer works perfectly in this scenario.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set the store first:

```
$store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(1);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($quoteId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` is like all the other db based models. You make something wrong. Maybe hardcode the `$quoteId`? Are you sure it is correct? Both codes should work.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using the an integer in place of `$quoteId`. I'm starting to think maybe `$quoteId` needs to be a string or something. My script is currently running, so I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work on another instance, either, with the quote entity ID hard-corded in string or integer. Fabian, have you tried the piece of the code I've posted?

Comment: While the model is just like other db models, the resource model Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote implements a hardcoded filter on store id by _getLoadSelect(). The way around it is to use `Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quote, $order->getQuoteId())`. Now if only I can tell it to NOT load a full customer object and start a session, I'm a happy camper.

Comment: For anyone facing the same: it's the SalesRule/Model/Observer.php that instantiates a session on quote items load. Just to get to the customerGroupId. I've solved this by rewrite Sales_Model_Quote and setting the customer group id in  Mage::registry and teaching Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer->addProductAttributes to first look there.

Comment: Please add this as an answer!

Comment: Sorry Fabian, topic is closed as off-topic. Even though this one is high ranked when searching for similar problems ;)

Comment: Just saw this. I voted to re-open. Thanks Melvyn.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
```

It works in Magnto Enterprise ver. 1.14.2.4